# Magento: Random "Featured Product"

Tags: magento

My client needs a a small box on CMS pages and on Category landing pages that will show thumbnail/price/short description of a random item related to that category (separate from the grid view)
Any thoughts on what would be the best way to accomplish this?
Thanks,
-Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to template/catalog/product/view/ and make a new phtml file random_product.phtml with the following code

```
<?php
$catId = $this->getCat_id();
$cat=Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
$prodCollection = $cat->getProductCollection();
$pids=array();
foreach($prodCollection as $product)
{
        array_push($pids,$product->getId());
}
$randProductId=array_rand($pids);
echo $randProductId;
?>
```

now if your category id is for example 10, make a static block and paste the following code in the contents

```
{{block type="catalog/product" cat_id="10" template="catalog/product/view/random_product.phtml"}}
```

now when you will view the static block, you will see a random product id every time you refresh. 
THen,you can write your own custom html in the phtml file after loading the product.

To load your product from here you can do `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId);` then call methods such as `$product->getName()` etc to get the details you need to output.

Comment: Thanks. I made random_product.phtml. Where do I put the next 2 pieces of code?

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product" cat_id="10" template="catalog/product/view/random_product.phtml"}} has to be put in the static block that is selected in the category with id "10". next pieces of code go in random_product.phtml

Comment: Thanks Major Help Sulabh. I'm getting it spit out the random ID now, but I can't seem to get the name or picture to render. Does this look ok? `code <?php
$catId = $this->getCat_id();
$cat=Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
$prodCollection = $cat->getProductCollection();
$pids=array();
foreach($prodCollection as $product)
{
        array_push($pids,$product->getId());
}
$randProductId=array_rand($pids);
echo $randProductId;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId);
$product->getName()
?>`

Comment: Check with assign any category manually as 3, 4, etc...  Ex: $catId = 3;

Comment: the last line should be    echo $product->getName();

Comment: you may look at list.phtml in catalog/product folder to know how to render various attributes of the loaded product

Comment: I can get it to display the image url; but if I add html tags I get errors; How do I put the image url within an img tag? (sorry my PHP is not expert) `code <?php
$catId = $this->getCat_id();
$cat=Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
$prodCollection = $cat->getProductCollection();
$pids=array();
foreach($prodCollection as $product)
{
        array_push($pids,$product->getId());
}
$randProductId=array_rand($pids);
echo $randProductId;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId);
$product->getName();
echo $product->getImageUrl();
?>
`

Comment: anything written between <?php ?> must be a php code. html is written outside php tags

Comment: <php catId = $this->getCat_id(); ..... $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId); ?> <img src = "<?php echo $product->getImageUrl();?>" >

Comment: you should look at phtml files and see how <?php ?> tags are used within html tags to render the full html

Comment: Beginners mistake... Thanks Sulabh. Your were a big help!

Comment: Hey Sulabh, Now that I have it styled I noticed the code is pulling any product; and is not filtering based on the category ID... Any ideas? I don't need to specify Cat. ID in the PHTML file do I?

Comment: ok there is a small mistake i guess. instead of 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($randProductId)
write
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pids[$randProductId])

Comment: array_rand gives you a random key from the array. to get the value u need to reference the array with that key